# Wrong Answer for n = 656 Nth Fibonacci Number using Dynamic Programmin

Tags: recursion, dynamic-programming, fibonacci, recurrence

```
class Solution {
  public:
  
    
    long long int nthFibonacci(long long int n){
        // code here
        //TABULATION
        long long int lookup[1001];
        lookup[0]=0;
        lookup[1]=1;
        for(long long int i=2;i<=n;i++){
            lookup[i]=lookup[i-1]+lookup[i-2];
        }
        return (lookup[n]%1000000007);
    }
};
```

When I submit it on GFG, it is showing that your code is giving wrong output for n=656

Wrong Answer. !!!Wrong Answer

Possibly your code doesn't work correctly for multiple test-cases (TCs).

The first test case where your code failed:

Input:
656

Its Correct output is:
823693831

And Your Code's output is:
-584713349

Comment: I'd guess overflow when filling out the table. If you only want the fibonacci numbers mod 1000000007 you should fill the table with the fibonacci numbers mod 1000000007. Morover I'd use unsigned integers as they don't invoke UB on overflow

Comment: @dmuir If you can please explain more or provide some link where I can research on this topic.

Comment: @dmuir seems like what you pointed out was right but can you please explain it in a little more detail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fibonacci numbers grow quite quickly.

```
fib(n) / (pow(phi, n)) -> 1/sqrt(5) as n -> infinity
where phi is the golden ratio, phi ~= 1.618
```

This means that fib(n) requires around

```
n*log2(phi)-0.5log2(5) ~ 0.694*(n-2) bits.
```

so fib(656) needs about 452 bits.
A long long int is unlikely to be that big!

In your original code the table, of long long ints, cannot hold the correct result for the larger fibonacci numbers.

In C (and I think C++) it is awkward to detect and correct overflow. It is better to ensure that it never happens. In your case you only want the fibonacci numbers mod m (m=1000000007). So you can fill the table with the fibonacci numbers mod m instead. Since m fits in 32 bits, all numbers modulo that and the sum of two of them fit in  32 bits and so overflow cannot occur.

By the way you have some redundant mods in your amended code; you could have

```
for(long long int i=2;i<=n;i++){
    lookup[i]=(lookup[i-1]+lookup[i-2])%mod;
}
```

bacause when you use it lookup[i-1] has already been reduced mod m.

Answer (score 0):

Update: found the correct solution to the problem but still don't know what was wrong with my earlier code
If someone can have a look at the correct solution and point out my mistake..Thanks in advance!!
Correct Solution:

```
class Solution {
  public:
  
    
    long long int nthFibonacci(long long int n){
        // code here
        //TABULATION
        const long long int mod=1000000007;
        long long int lookup[1001];
        lookup[0]=0;
        lookup[1]=1;
        for(long long int i=2;i<=n;i++){
            lookup[i]=(lookup[i-1]%mod+lookup[i-2]%mod)%mod;
        }
        return lookup[n];
    }
};
```